# Counting selected dataframe columns according to condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Although this question seems somewhat similar to previous ones, I could not have it solved with previous answers and I need help from experts.

I am trying to create a column (e.g. 'Result') with the count of other columns with labels that start with 'X_', given a condition (eg. column element >1).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0, 2], [2, 3, 1], [3, 0, 3]]), columns=['A', 'X_1', 'X_2'])
df1

    A   X_1 X_2
0   1   0   2
1   2   3   1
2   3   0   3
```

The desired output is:

```
df1
    A   X_1 X_2 Result
0   1   0   2   1
1   2   3   1   2
2   3   0   3   1
```

Can you please help me?

A novice Panda user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) the DataFrame for columns that start with `X_` test which values are [`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) (greater than or equal to) 1 and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to count the number of values that are `True` for each row (`axis=1`):

```
df1['Result'] = df1.filter(regex='^X_').ge(1).sum(axis=1)
```

`df1`:

```
   A  X_1  X_2  Result
0  1    0    2       1
1  2    3    1       2
2  3    0    3       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `gt` and `sum`:

```
>>> df1['Result'] = df1.gt(0).sum(1) - df1['A'].gt(0)
>>> df1
   A  X_1  X_2  Result
0  1    0    2       1
1  2    3    1       2
2  3    0    3       1
>>>
```

Comment: Only for columns start with "X_"